# Retrieve Detail Description of RSS feeds

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, rss

I have use the RSS link "http://pnlhosting.com/boldi2/feed"

In this i have read "Title","Date" correctly
But while i try to retrive "Detail description" - i got some information & some html tags

```
        NSString *articleTitle = [item valueForChild:@"title"];//correct
        NSString *articleUrl = [item valueForChild:@"link"];//correct
        NSString *articleDateString = [item valueForChild:@"pubDate"];//correct

        NSString *articleDescription = [item valueForChild:@"description"];//not correct
```

I got the result as...

articleDescription = Girato tra Miami e le isole Bahamas il film racconta i preparativi di matrimonio, fra due famiglie: i Colombo, italiani di umili origini guidati dal tassista Cristoforo (Massimo Boldi) e dalla moglie Rosy (Sconsolata), e i Di Giacomo, italoamericani ricchissimi … [Continue reading →](http://pnlhosting.com/boldi2/2012/05/matrimonio-alle-bahamas-regia-di-claudio-risi-2007/)

How can I get the cleared description?